# Struts 1 custom validator

Tags: validation, struts

I need to write custom validator which will simply check an array of strings for malformed data. This array of course comes from form as a property and actually it values comes from request through html:multibox tags (these are simple ID of elements in a string form). So I want to validate this data.

The problem is that official guide has nothing to say about handling non-string properties. I don't know how to retrieve this array.

Here is the example from struts valiator guide:

```
public static boolean validateTwoFields(
Object bean,
ValidatorAction va, 
Field field,
ActionErrors errors,
HttpServletRequest request, 
ServletContext application) {

String value = ValidatorUtils.getValueAsString(
    bean, 
    field.getProperty());
String sProperty2 = field.getVarValue("secondProperty");
String value2 = ValidatorUtils.getValueAsString(
    bean, 
    sProperty2);

if (!GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(value)) {
   try {
      if (!value.equals(value2)) {
         errors.add(field.getKey(),
            Resources.getActionError(
                application,
                request,
                va,
                field));

         return false;
      }
   } catch (Exception e) {
         errors.add(field.getKey(),
            Resources.getActionError(
                application,
                request,
                va,
                field));
         return false;
   }
}

return true;
```

}

As you can see this perfectly explains how to handle string values, but what about other types ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should use [PropertyUtils.getProperty()](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) and then make use of the Object returned. You can see the example mentioned in the link below:

http://www.webkaifa.com/jsp/jakartaStrutsCookbook/059600771x/jakartastrutsckbk-chp-8-sect-9.html